# Displaying data from two MYSQL databases with both same table and table fields names

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have two databases that I want to display on one table. They are normalUser database with table `users` and admin database with table `users`. Since they are sign up systems, they have same table fields. That is `user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass, joining_date`. 
Question, I want to display their contents on a table and include their roles based on the database name. normalUser for normalUser database and admin role for admin database. I can not think of a MYSQLI SELECT statement to achieve this, anyone? Thank you.

```
//admin database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "ub435!";
$dbname = "adm";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//normal user database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "ub435!";
$dbname = "normaluser";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY joining_date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     echo " <table><tr><th>ID</th><th>User Name</th>
<th>Email</th><th>Password</th><th>Joining Date</th>
</tr>";

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr>";

echo '<td>' . $row['user_id'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['user_name'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['user_email'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['user_pass'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['joining_date'] . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
} else { 
 echo "You have no Users.";
}
```

Comment: can you not just make a column or a table wich says what permission/role a user has? It seems a little over the top what you are trying to do, maybe because I don't fully understand what your goals is.

Comment: How do I get the database in a table column for the role?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a UNION because mysql allows a database to be specified in a query

> You can refer to a table within the default database as tbl_name, or
>   as db_name.tbl_name to specify a database explicitly. You can refer to
>   a column as col_name, tbl_name.col_name, or db_name.tbl_name.col_name.
>   You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a
>   column reference unless the reference would be ambiguous. See Section
>   10.2.1, “Identifier Qualifiers”, for examples of ambiguity that require the more explicit column reference forms.

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Thus your query becomes.

```
SELECT adm.users.*, 'admin' as role FROM adm.users
UNION
SELECT normaluser.users.*, 'simple' as role FROM normaluser.users
ORDER BY joining_date DESC"
```

**Update based on additional information requested.**

Don't open two separate connections to the databases. Open one connection but without the database name parameter.

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

Use this connection for all subsequent queries on this page. that means instead of just `users` you would either have to do `adm.users` or `normaluser.users` every on on this page.

I have updated the query above to reflect actual table names.

**Side note:**
Try not to use the root account in web apps

Comment: I have two databases: 
`$dbname = "fundblogin";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 die($conn->connect_error);

                                                                                                                                                                                                     

$dbname = "funadmindb";
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`    How do I insert the same in the Union? Kindly.

Comment: Please add this as a part of the question. Generally changing a question after it has been answered is frowned upon on SO (eg http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer) however, I will acede your request and edit my answer once the question is updated.

Comment: Done I have included. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [UNION operator](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

```
SELECT *, 'normal' AS role FROM normalUser.users u
UNION
SELECT *, 'admin AS role FROM admin.users a
```

The column names and order must be the same. If the orders differ, then list the columns in the same order in the `SELECT` clause (`SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name...`)

Comment: I have two databases: 
`$dbname = "fundblogin";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 die($conn->connect_error);

                                                                                                                                                                                                     

$dbname = "funadmindb";
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`    How do I insert the same in the Union? Kindly.